# Make a bootstrap Modal, relative to a column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have 3 columns in my design and I want a modal to be placed inside the second column. And the modal shouldn't move outside the 2nd column when the screen size is changed (only on desktop sizes (1922x1080 - 1280x600) ).

```css
.col{
height:100vh;
}

.column-two{
position:relative;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 200px !important;  height: 228px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
        
        
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col border">
      ONE
    </div>
    <div class="col border column-two">
      TWO
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col border" >
     THREE
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I'm planning to make the modal position relative and place it inside the column.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below custom css and check agian. i hope your issue will fix by this custom css.

```
.column-two .modal {
    position: absolute;
}

/* for center position */
.column-two .modal.show {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution:

```css
.col{
height:100vh;
}

.column-two{
position:relative;
}

#exampleModal{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
        
        
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col border">
      ONE
    </div>
    <div class="col border column-two">
      TWO
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col border" >
     THREE
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```